# How can I show the camera but not let the user take a photo?

Tags: objective-c, ios, camera

How can I let the user see the front facing camera, but prevent them from being able to take a picture, video, or switch to the rear camera on the iPhone 4/4s and/or the iPod Touch 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cameraPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
....
cameraPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
cameraPicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

Comment: When I copy the code in, it says that it cant find cameraPicker.  what else do I need to do?

Comment: @coryginsberg answer edited. a UIImagePickerController object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AVFoundation framework to open camera.

Try this sample code https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112 .